# PHP retrieving data from JSON lower levels in an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I know I'm missing something very basic here:

My json data looks like:

```
id: "123",
status: "SET",
  sections: [
    {
        key: "top_details",
        title: "top Details",
        fields: [
           {
             key: "order_id",
             value: "123456",
            },
            {
             key: "tracking_id",
             value: "98765",
      }
id: "456",
status: "UNSET",
    sections: [
        {
            key: "top_details",
            title: "top Details",
            fields: [
               {
                 key: "order_id",
                 value: "55555",
                },
                {
                 key: "tracking_id",
                 value: "77777",
          }
```

I can get the values from the top level using

```
foreach ($json as $key=>$value)

    {


    echo $value['id'];
    echo $value['status'];

    }
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to get the nested values under 'order_id' and 'tracking_id.'

Thank you and pardon my ignorance.

Comment: @IdanMagled Tried that. I get 'Warning: Illegal string offset 'sections'

Comment: @user2029890: `$value['sections']` is an array.  Loop over it and get its fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do.

```
foreach ($json as $key=>$value)
   {
        foreach($json['sections'] as $sections){
          foreach($sections['fields'] as $data){
             echo $data['key']."=".$data["value"];
        }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect. Confused at first, but I see you used $json instead of $value in the 2nd foreach. Once I replaced it, it worked fine. Certainly enough to accept the answer with a shout to @Rocket Hazmat who also gave the same answer without the full example.